# How to get world coordinates from screen coordinates in opengl es2.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es, projection

I am new to opengl. I am drawing a map in android using opengl ES2.0. When i touch on screen i am getting screen coordinates. i want these coordinates to be converted into world coordinates. The code i found through research is as follows:

```
vec3 UnProjectPoint( const vec3& Point, const max4& Projection, const mat4& ModelView )
{
    vec4 R( Point, 1.0f );

    R.x = 2.0f * R.x - 1.0f;
    R.y = 2.0f * R.y - 1.0f;
    R.y = -R.y;

    R.z = 1.0f;

    R = Projection.GetInversed() * R;
    R = ModelView.GetInversed() * R;

    return R.ToVec3();
}
```

but android is not allowing me to use vec3 and vec4?
I also use built in gluunproject function but this function is also not giving me correct results.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you just use an ortographic projection.
This worked for me in this 2d example project of mine:

- [Matrix.orthoM(mtrxProjection, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);](https://github.com/Karm/galgs/blob/master/src/cz/urbangaming/galgs/PointsRenderer.java#L69)

And then: Matrix.multiplyMM(...  Take a look in that aforementioned source.
In the vertex shader, you then simply use:

```
gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
```

Graphics
The whole application logic works with the screen coordinates and these are projected onto OpenGL coordinates within that vertex shader.

I'm just an OpenGL noob, so I don't know whether this is an optimal solution.

BTW: On Page 111 in this book: [Graphics Gems V.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0125434553) one can find a general approach to such transformations.

HTH